# Apache Camel AMQP with selector is consuming any message

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to use selectors on an amqp with Azure Service Bus consumer. However, for some reason the route is also consuming messages that do not match the selector.

Here's an example:

This route generates messages and append a header:

```
<route id="MessageGenerator">
    <from uri="timer:generator?delay=5000&amp;period=5000"/>

    <setHeader headerName="INSTANCE_ID">
        <simple>{{env:INSTANCE_ID}}</simple>
    </setHeader>

    <to uri="amqp:queue:external_queue" />
</route>
```

While this route should consume only those that contain INSTANCE_ID matching 2 possible values: env:INSTANCE_ID or Any.

```
<route id="ExternalConsumer">
    <from uri="amqp:queue:external_queue?selector=INSTANCE_ID IN ('{{env:INSTANCE_ID}}', 'Any')"/>

    <log message="{{env:INSTANCE_ID}} consumed message with Instance ID: ${header.INSTANCE_ID}" logName="AMQP_TEST" loggingLevel="INFO"/>
        
</route>
```

But the the log shows that it is consuming any message, regardless of the selector specifying which ones.

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue here was that Azure Service Bus does NOT support selectors on queues. I switched to topics, which already have filters per subscription.